# Node's spawn() silently failing when called from a forever script scheduled on boot

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

This is kind of a doozy. This issue is most likely server related and so my first recourse was [AskUbuntu over here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726991/how-to-autostart-node-forever-and-use-spawn-as-sudo-on-ubuntu).

I'm trying to have crontab or rc.local or init.d to start a [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) script on boot. It attaches a server to a port I can ping with some information and have it run a headless browser for me.

That said, it seems that I'm unable to get a response from  Node.js's `spawn()`:

```
var CASPER_PATH = '/home/ubuntu/dev/casperjs/bin/casperjs'; // actual binary location, not a symlink
var SCRIPTS_PATH = '/home/custom_user/endpoints/server.js';

var fileName = req.body.source + '_' + req.body.type + '.coffee'; // looks like: mysource_my_scrape_type.coffee
var scrapeId = 'test_scrape';
var user = 'user123';
var pass = 'pass123';
if (fs.existsSync(SCRIPTS_PATH + fileName)) {
  // If file is in place, spawn casperjs
  var sP = spawn(CASPER_PATH, 
    [SCRIPTS_PATH + fileName, '--ssl-protocol=any', '--user='+user, '--scrapeId='+scrapeId, '--pass='+pass], 
    { detached: true }, 
    function (err, stdout, stderr) {});
  sP.stdout.on('data', function(data) { console.log('stdout', data.toString('utf8')); });
  sP.stderr.on('data', function(data) { console.log('stderr', data.toString('utf8')); });
  sP.stdout.on('close', function(code) { console.log('close', code); });
  res.send({ scheduled: true, key: scrapeId });
} else {
  res.send({ scheduled: false, error: 'Incorrect source, type or the script is missing.' });
}
```

Before I added the `PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE` env to `crontab` or `rc.local` (doesnt seem to matter no matter the user level), stdout was useful:

> stdout Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install
>   phantomjs?
>
> close false

Now that the environment var is there, there is no output at all after `spawn()`.

Mind you, Casper starts up just fine if a user (of any privilege level) runs node/forever from bash.

How can I see why `spawn()` is failing?

Comment: Can you include the full source of your script? What exactly is `spawn`? I just looked at [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) and there is no error callback to child_process.spawn(), if you use this `spawn` then try to add sP.on('error', ..) handler and check the output. Also it would be good if you post your crontab or init.d, so it would be easier to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually looks like a combo-bug between forever, spawn and casperjs (maybe phantomjs).
I was able to reproduce your problem, [here is](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/tree/master/nodejs-casperjs) the full code of my test application.

You didn't show the full code, so my guess is that you have an express application and there is a special URL to run the casperjs script.

I build a simple app like this and it behaved this way:

- Just start app with `node script.js` (`script.js` is the express app which runs the casperjs script in `server.js`) - it works OK, renders response and writes output from the child process event handlers to console
- Start app as root with init.d script - doesn't work, once the child is spawned, no event handlers are triggered
- Start app as root with init.d script, replace casperjs with `echo` - the same, doesn't work (see, here we have this problem with just `forever` running as root, `spawn` and `echo`)
- Start app as a regular user (not root) with init.d, replace casperjs with 'echo' - it works, event handlers are triggered, here I was almost sure the issue is solved, but ... :(
- Start app as a regular user (not root) with init.d, put back casperjs - it doesn't work again, event handlers are not triggered

The practical solution to this it to use [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2), I did this:

```shell
# install pm2
sudo npm install -g pm2
# generate init.d scripts for pm2
# this command will fail, but hint about the correct format with sudo
pm2 startup ubuntu
# do this in the folder with your application
pm2 start script.js
# remember your application
pm2 save
# also useful
# sudo service stop/start/restart pm2
# pm2 stop/start/restart script
```

Now `pm2` will start automatically with the system and it will launch your application. Everything works, child process event handlers are triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your requirement completely. But i do have a similar situation with Ubuntu headless server.

what i am trying to do here is what i did

First, How is my crontab ?

```
crontab -u USER -e

@reboot exec sudo -u USER /bin/bash /home/USER/SHELL_SCRIPT.sh
```

See, here i am actually starting a shell script, and not a node server

Now inside this shell script(SHELL_SCRIPT.sh)

```
    #! /bin/bash
    # SHELL_SCRIPT.sh
    cd /home/USER/
    /home/USER/.npm-packages/bin/forever start -p /home/USER -a -d --watch false --pidFile /home/USER/forever.pid -l /home/USER/forever.log -o /home/USER/forever.out -e /home/USER/forever.err /home/USER/MY_NODE.js
```

and even inside my MY_NODE.js  i follow absolute path, i just ignore $PATH, and don't use that.

Inside this node server, I do 100's of spawn

Now, i did this around 2 years back,  so if you ask me why do this way,  which i cannot answer

Comment: Do you spawn casper or phantom specifically?

Comment: No, I spawn lot of other things and I avoid $PATH even in that spawned process